Webmethods - fine grained text search
I need to perform a text search on a large webmethods project.
It needs to be pretty fine grained - eg say I suspect that some Map step, somewhere, is assigning hardcoded value "22567" into a variable. I'd like to search for "22567" and that the search would got deep enough to show such map steps.
Is there any way to achieve this please? Either through the eclispe Designer, or any other method?
Thanks
Tried normal eclispe search with no results
